# Expo 34: Error Undefined is not an object on _expo.Constants.deviceId

Tags: sdk, expo, deviceid

[image]

I received below message after upgrade my expo project from sdk 33 to 34. I have no idea where this issue is from. Does anyone have this error before.

Comment: Hello i have the same issue, did you find how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

install expo-constants package
change import to

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

you can use Constants.installationId and not deviceId.